# How do I add to a ListBox using a method in another class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, listbox, shopping-cart

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. [This is a screenshot of my form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNJvf.jpg)

I have two classes, ShoppingBasket and OrderItem, and then the Form1 class. I have four properties in OrderItem that I want to use in ShoppingBasket. I want to take the product name in textbox1, the quantity in numericupdown1, and the latest price in textbox2, then I will click the add button which will validate the values using the OrderItem class, then put them into the AddProduct method in the ShoppingBasket class which will hopefully add a line to the listbox in the form.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal latestPrice;

        ShoppingBasket addButtonShoppingBasket = new ShoppingBasket();

        decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out latestPrice);
        OrderItem currentItemQuantity1 = new OrderItem(textBox1.Text, latestPrice, Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));

        addButtonShoppingBasket.AddProduct(currentItemQuantity1.ProductName, currentItemQuantity1.LatestPrice, currentItemQuantity1.Quantity);
    }
}
```

ShoppingBasket:

```
public class ShoppingBasket
{
    public ShoppingBasket()
    {

    }

    public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestProductValue, int quantity)
    {
        Form1 newform = new Form1();

        string itemFormatString = "{0,-50}{1,0}{2,50}";
        newform.listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format(itemFormatString, productName, Convert.ToString(quantity), Convert.ToString(latestProductValue)));
    }
}
```

OrderItem:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public OrderItem(string productName, decimal latestPrice, int quantity)
    {
        ProductName = productName;
        LatestPrice = latestPrice;
        Quantity = quantity;
        TotalOrder = latestPrice * quantity;
    }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public decimal LatestPrice { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you're having?

Comment: Why not just return the string and add in the form, instead of adding in the method? Your method doesn't have to be `void`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange - It says 'listBox1 is inaccessible due to itsprotection level', so I don't think I'm doing it right that way. Any idea?

Comment: @YoryeNathan I've done it this way because it's working from a booklet, but we're only given the class names and method names.

Comment: @user2299950 That's because the listbox belongs to the form, not to the `ShoppingBasket` class. You need to send the order item to form1 and have it add it to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that you are creating a new form from your `ShoppingBasked`, whenever a product is added:

```
public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestProductValue, int quantity)
{
    Form1 newform = new Form1();

    string itemFormatString = "{0,-50}{1,0}{2,50}";
    newform.listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format(itemFormatString, productName, Convert.ToString(quantity), Convert.ToString(latestProductValue)));
}
```

`newform` is not the form that actually called `AddProduct`! Even if you do not see this `newform` anywhere (because `newform.Show()` isn't called), the list item get's added to this "invisible" form, not the original one.

To solve this problem, I suggest passing your form as parameter to `AddProduct`:

```
public void AddProduct(Form1 form, string productName, decimal latestProductValue, int quantity)
{
    string itemFormatString = "{0,-50}{1,0}{2,50}";
    form.listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format(itemFormatString, productName, Convert.ToString(quantity), Convert.ToString(latestProductValue)));
}
```

And call it like this:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    // Your current code here
    // ...

    addButtonShoppingBasket.AddProduct(this, 
        currentItemQuantity1.ProductName, 
        currentItemQuantity1.LatestPrice, 
        currentItemQuantity1.Quantity);
}
```

Also an general advice to continue is changing your design. At the moment, `ShoppingBasket` is highly coupled to `Form1` - this means, you cannot add new items to your shopping basket from any other source than a `Form1`! But `ShoppingBasket` should not care about the source of the item it receives. Also at the moment you create a new `ShoppingBasket`, each time you insert an item. This means, you can only have one item per `ShoppingBasket`. So for further learning, I suggest following those points:

- Make `ShoppingBasket` a member variable of `Form1`.
- When adding items, add the item to this member variable.
- Do not pass your form to `AddProduct`, instead make your `ShoppingBasket` provide information about the items it contains.
- Call `listBox1.Items.Add` right after `AddProduct`.

Then your `ShoppingBasket` does not care about how your products are presented, it only cares about how the products are stored internally.